Traveling to Colombia with an Indian passport and US Visa that expires in 100 days
I have an Indian passport with a US visa that expires in 100 days and not 180 days.
Can I still enter Colombia, given I don’t meet the 180 day rule?

OK, I see it now.  This is related to Can an Indian citizen holding a valid USA visa visit Colombia without a visa?, and specifically this answer.

No.  To qualify for the visa exemption, the visa must be valid for at least six months when you enter Colombia (the document from the Colombian government linked below says "six months," not 180 days).  Your visa will be valid for a shorter period, so it will not qualify you for the exemption.
Reference: A. Visa Waiver: Nationalities and Special Conditions - Cancillería (pdf), a document from the Colombian government
Also see Advisory for Indians Travelling to Colombia, a page from the Indian embassy to Colombia in Bogota.
You could try to get a new US visa before your trip, but it is likely to be simpler to try to get a Colombian visa instead.
